# I want Java Pattern.compile to recognize positive or negative integers or decimals

Tags: java, regex

In Java I want to use Pattern.compile(String regexp) to find a negative or positive integer or decimal.

Ex. (1) (11) (1.1) (11.11) (-1) (-11) (-1.1) (-11.11)

I have found several answers online that tell me this is the correct regexp, but it ignores "-" sign ever single time.

```
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("(\\-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)");
```

Comment: It's working here: https://regex101.com/r/1FzP14/1

Comment: i don't think you have to escape a dash when it isn't inside a character class... also the outer parens aren't doing anything:  `-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?`

Comment: @Rims That does not match non-decimal numbers like 1, -1 ...

Comment: when you say "ignores" the minus sign, what do you mean? it either matches it or doesn't...

Comment: [Your regex works well](https://regex101.com/r/LP7mFG/1).

Comment: Check my answer, if you want to include the parenthesis use this `[(][+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+[)]` I have provided sample code.

Comment: You all misunderstood. My example was just showing you guys what numbers I want to pull from a string, the parenthesis do not mean anything. I just want the number, but sometimes the number might be one of those variations. No matter the number, the negative sign is always left out. So, say the number come sin as -259.12, the pattern.compile should return -259.12, but it returns 259.12 for some reason and ignores the "-".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("(-|\\+)?\\d+");
```

That should match both positive and negative integer numbers.

For decimals (should match either integers or decimals):

```
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("(-|\\+)?\\d+((\\.{1}\\d+)?)");
```

Comment: @Prexx That should not match decimals.

Comment: But he wants it :) "to find a negative or positive integer or decimal." Maybe you could add it in your approach?

Comment: Added a pattern to match decimals.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String regex = "(-)?\\d+([.]\\d+)?";
```

We allow one optional minus (-)? for negative numbers and one optional decimal point ([.]) followed by digits (\d) for decimal numbers.

```
 String regex = "(-)?\\d+([.]\\d+)?";
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
 String input = "-0.123";
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(scr);
 System.out.println(matcher.matches()); //Prints true.
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your pattern and it works fine. Maybe I didnt understand the question but here is the source code I used.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Play {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)");

        Matcher m = p.matcher("(1) (11) (1.1) (11.11) (-1) (-11) (-1.1) (-11.11)");

        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Found a " + m.group());
        }

    }
}
```

And The outcome is

```
run:

Found a 1
Found a 11
Found a 1.1
Found a 11.11
Found a -1
Found a -11
Found a -1.1
Found a -11.11
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

If you want to include the parenthesis as well then use this pattern
`[(][+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+[)]`

Comment: Maybe he wants (1), (-1) ... to match. That would explain the unnecessary outer braces that has to be escaped.

Comment: @Prexx True, I added another expression

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: for some reason the "-" is not be recognized, so I tried the unicode version and regexp allows unicode by doing \u2212 a.k.a. (\-). This solved my issue and i have no idea why it wouldnt work before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(-?(\\d+(\\.?\\d+)))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(YourString);
//m.group(1);
```